# Grocery List Troubles

Tags: java, class, oop

Trying to complete a Grocery list program for an assignment that totals the price of each item and returns a total cost. This is what I have so far:

The main:

```
public class Grocery {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GroceryList list = new GroceryList();  
    list.add ("carrots", 5, 0.40);  
    list.add ("apples", 4, 0.15);  
    list.add ("rice", 1, 1.10);  
    list.add ("tortillas", 10, .05);  
    list.add ("strawberries", 1, 4.99);  
    list.add ("chicken", 1, 5.99);  
    list.add ("lettuce", 1, 0.99);  
    list.add ("milk", 2, 2.39);  
    list.add ("yogurt", 3, 0.60);  
    list.add ("chocolate", 1, 3.99);  

GroceryList Test = new GroceryList();
System.out.println(Test.getTotalCost());
}
}
```

The GroceryList class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GroceryList {

    public double itemcost = 0;

    private String nameList[];
    private int quantityList[];
    private double priceList[];

    private GroceryItemOrder[] list = null;

    public int num;

    public GroceryList() {

        list = new GroceryItemOrder[10];
        this.num = 0;

}

public void add(String name, int quantity, double price) {
    if (num < 10) {
        nameList[num] = name;
        quantityList[num] = quantity;
        priceList[num] = price;
        num++;

    }

}

public double getTotalCost() {
    double totalcost = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        totalcost = totalcost + quantityList[i] + priceList[i]; 
    }
    System.out.println(totalcost);
    return totalcost;
}

}
```

And the GroceryItemOrder class:

```
public class GroceryItemOrder {
private String name;
private double pricePerUnit;
private int quantity;

public GroceryItemOrder(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit) {

    this.name = name;
    this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
    this.quantity = quantity;

}

public double getCost() {

    return (this.quantity * this.pricePerUnit);
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {

    this.quantity = quantity;

}

}
```

I keep getting the output 0.0 (like 20 times) when I try to add a println to the add function in order to test, so I am guessing that it isn't passing the information into the arrays for whatever reason, or it has trouble reading from them, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you're printing out the cost of the GroceryList TEST, not the GroceryList LIST! since u didnt add anything to the TEST list, it returns  0

I guess what u want is

```
    list.getTotalCost ();
```